# Do I have to change my web application structure because of this issue?

Tags: java, jquery, wildfly

I'm using form basic authentication and the login process is working fine.

The login and error page are both index.jsp where I do have another post method that calls the page itself, but when trying to read the parameters from jquery ajax data parameter, null value is returned.

If parameters are sended next to url or using header, I can read the parameters e.g:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/?data=data", // Ok
    headers: {xdata: data}, // Ok
    data: {fail: "data"}, // fails
```

This is the code used in index.jsp to read the parameters:

```
if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")) {
    System.out.prinltn("data from url "
        + request.getParameter("data")); // parameter is printed
    System.out.prinltn("data from header: "
        + request.getHeader("xdata")); // parameter is printed
    System.out.prinltn("data from fail: "
        + request.getParameter("fail")); // null is printed here
    return;
}
```

All resources are secured in web.xml and this is where things become interesting:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

If change the pattern to e.g <url-pattern>/other/*</url-pattern>, the fail parameter is printed!.
So, is there a way to post data to index.jsp and make things to work without changing url-pattern in web.xml?

Comment: I think you have to write `... data: {'fail': 'data'} ...`. Further you can get information about the error in the `error` and the `complete` [methods of ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Next you should share the error information here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!. Tried your recommendations about sending data: {'fail': 'data'}, but also fails. And for ajax methods, always get response status code 200 from server. Don't really know why of this behavior, I think that it's something related to java security because if change the url-pattern in web.xml all works fine and can get the data send from jquery. The thing is that I don't want to change the security that way...